# PropertyChangeSupport leaks this reference

Tags: java

I have a bean which contains a private field PropertyChangeSupport pcs. If i invoke pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this) inside bean constructor then i'm not sure whether this approach potentially dangerous or not. What do you think about leaking this reference in constructor in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any danger. The `PropertyChangeSupport` is not going to do anything dangerous with `this`, there's not going to be any way for `this` to get to another thread from it.

Comment: so if PropertyChangeSupport now is public field and referenced by other classes, what would happen, is that safe approach?

Comment: If it's `public final`, it could be safe.